# App crashes after selecting option on AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities and use `AlertDialog`. Whenever I click an option of the `AlertDialog`, my app crashed. I'm trying to pass the selected option to Second Activity using Intent. Here's some of the code.

**MainActivity**

```
if (d == R.id.play_btn) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose")
                    .setSingleChoiceItems(difficultyNames, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selected) {
                           dialogInterface.dismiss();
                            startPlay(selected);
                        }
                    });
            // Creates the dialog
            AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
            ad.show();
        }

  private void startPlay(int selected) {
        // start gameplay
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, GameplayActivity.class);
        playIntent.putExtra("level", selected);
        this.startActivity(playIntent);
    }
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extras != null) {
      int passedLevel = extras.getInt("level", 0);
      if (passedLevel >= 0) level = passedLevel;
 }
```

**Crash Log**

```
11:51:12 PM Broken pipe
            java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
            at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.a... (show balloon)
11:53:02 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:53:31 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:53:42 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:04 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:05 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:19 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:20 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:42 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:43 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:48 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:53 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:54:54 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:55:01 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger
11:55:51 PM Broken pipe
            java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
            at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.a... (show balloon)
12:02:50 AM Broken pipe
            java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
            at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.a... (show balloon)
12:05:58 AM Broken pipe
            java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
            at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.a... (show balloon)
12:13:29 AM Broken pipe
            java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.write(JdwpPacket.java:179)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.send(Client.java:654)
            at com.android.ddmlib.jdwp.JdwpAgent.send(JdwpAgent.java:92)
            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:517)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:507)
            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:403)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post your logcat error ?

Comment: Sorry, stack didn't allow me format the log properly

Comment: There is no information about the error here.. Are you sure you copied the right log? There should be something like `JavaException` somewhere...

Comment: Your USB debugger is not properly plugged in. :)

Comment: Problem solved. It wasn't from my USB cable. I didn't reference one of my ImageView. Thanks for caring.

Comment: improves formatting and explanations

Comment: if your problem get solved then you can delete this question.